# Why is my vector not being written to code?

Tags: c++, output, iostream

My main task is to sort the vector with the class of letters in the future, but for a reason that is not clear to me, the vector is not recorded, only the first line of the user’s mail.
This is my header

```cpp
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct date {
    int day{ 1 };
    int month{ 1 };
    int year{ 1999 };

    date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this->day = day;
        this->month = month;
        this->year = year;
    }

    date() = default;

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, date& date) {
        is >> date.day >> date.month >> date.year;
        return is;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const date& date) {
        os << date.day << "." << date.month << "." << date.year;
        return os;
    }
};

class letter {
public:
    string sender{ "None" };
    string message;
    date when;

    string Get_sender() {
        return sender;
    }

    string Get_message() {
        return message;
    }

    date Get_date() {
        return when;
    }

    letter() = default;

    letter(string sender, string message, date when)
        : sender(sender), message(message), when(when) {}

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, letter& mes) {
        is >> mes.sender;
        char quote;
        is >> ws >> quote;
        getline(is, mes.message, '"');
        is >> mes.when;
        return is;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const letter& letterObj) {
        os << "Sender: " << letterObj.sender << endl;
        os << "Message: " << letterObj.message << endl;
        os << "Date: " << letterObj.when << endl;
        return os;
    }
};

class Email {
public:
    vector<letter> letters;
    string userName{ "None" };

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Email& mail) {
        is >> mail.userName;
        return is;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Email& mail) {
        os << "User name: " << mail.userName << endl;
        os << "Vector letters:" << endl;
        for (const letter& letterObj : mail.letters) {
            os << letterObj << endl;
        }
        return os;
    }
};

#endif // !CLASS_H
```

main cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char FileName[100];
    cout << "Which file should I enter data from?\n";
    cin.getline(FileName, sizeof(FileName));
    ifstream fin(FileName);
    Email email;
    if (fin.is_open()) {
        fin >> email;
        letter temp;
        while (fin >> temp) {
            email.letters.push_back(temp);
        }
        fin.close();
        cout << email << endl;
        cout << "Which file should I output the data to?\n";
        cin.getline(FileName, sizeof(FileName));
        ofstream fout(FileName);
        if (fout.is_open())
        {
            fout << email;
            fout.close();
            cout << "Data output to file " << FileName << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error writing to file " << FileName << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File " << FileName << " not found\n";
    }

    Sleep(7654);
    return 0;
}
```

and my file data.txt:

```
mymail5@pochta.com 
danila@pochta.com "I love my mom" 17.08.2023 
gleb@pochta.com "HABIBATI" 13.09.2024 
ImFromChina@pochta.com "This is my 4720 year!" 31.12.4719
```

I think there is either a problem in ostream or in reading a file from the stream. My vector is not written when reading.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Also, you should have just tested basic file reading of your data first before writing all of this code.  Instead you have written an entire program without knowing if the basic file reading is working correctly.  Also, `using namespace std;` should not be in header files.

Comment: Another side note: your `date` struct's constructor should use a member initialization list.

Comment: The stream inserter writes a `date` object in a format that the stream extractor cannot read. If the inserter writes spaces instead of dots the extractor will be able to read it. If the dots are important, the extractor has to deal with them; not a big deal, but necessary.

Comment: Seems very likely to me that your code is failing to read more than one record. Which will obviously then be the reason you only see one record output. As already said, too much code, too little testing. Don't start testing only when you have finished the program, test every step of the way.

Comment: FYI, if you use a naming convention where members are different names than parameters, you don't need to use the `this->` syntax.  Less typing means less chance of typos.

Comment: *"My main task is to sort [X]"* -- I don't see any attempt to sort in your code. I think (sorry, your text is not clear) that this "main task" is not relevant to your question. What seems to be relevant is that your **current** task is to read `letter` objects from a file. If that is accurate, then there is no need for an output file in your [mre]. Just output each `letter` that is read, as soon as it is read, as in `while (fin >> temp) {
std::cout << temp << "\n";
}`. **Keep the example code simple.** Drop the `Email` class if you can demonstrate the issue without it.